# Blender FBX Export causes artifacts in weight painting

Tags: export, weight-painting, .fbx

using the blender FBX export is creating these artifacts, as seen in the image. I've done a little playing with the export settings so far but nothing exhaustive.

I've already checked the scaling of the model and armature within blender, that's not what it is.
[image: Before & After FBX export, and settings]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the full ramifications of this and I doubt it's a true solution, but ticking "Armature -> Only Deform Bones" under FBX export settings fixed the problem for me.